# Where to start Handwritten Text Recognition using Neural Network in C# or any language

Tags: c#, java, c++, visual-c++

I am doing project on hand written text recognition systems. I need help where to start.......

Comment: Tell us what you've got so far and someone may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I were interested in a project like that I think I would like...I dunno...go to the library and get some books or something.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good bit on information on this topic here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/NeuralNetRecognition.aspx and there's also a paper on the topic here http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~hinton/absps/ijcai05.pdf .  This isn't really my area, but honestly your question is really open-ended and kind of hard to answer.  This is a fairly large topic, however, so you should be able to find something in university papers like the one I linked or in any discussions of currently implemented systems like Palm's, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Start with understanding of "What is a neural network" ?

What are its various types  and properties of each network type

Then, learn about feedback mechanism and understand error propagation and learning mechanism through hidden layers

Then create a tree - based data structure in C/C++ and try to have network representation in your model

http://www.learnartificialneuralnetworks.com/